# XSS in the chat room name that are displayed in MSO

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, xss

The recent chat feature that was added recently has a XSS flaw in it. For testing purpose, I created a chat room called `<b>123</b>` and as you can see in the screenshot below, the `<b>` tags weren't escaped.

[image]

Comment: You should probably illustrate the importance of this bug by making a chat room that causes people on meta to automatically upvote this post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice catch. I guess someone owes you a beer next time you meet in `The Tavern<script>alert('General')</script>`.